# ngIf works only on page refresh

Tags: angular

I am using oxford API in my angular application.I am using two different endpoints ,first is entries and the other is the thesaurus. 
I want to present data only if it exists using ngIf. This works with the entries endpoint but not with the thesaurus.
If a word doesn't have any synonyms and antonyms , these two properties shouldn't be displayed.But in my application it is not working as expected.
For example if I search for 'good' its data get displayed including synonyms and antonyms.And if search for a word like 'hanami' next,it gets an error from thesaurus endpoint stating not found.But still the synonyms and antonyms are displayed from the previous result which is the word 'good'.Only after I refresh the page those two are removed.

Here is component.ts file

```
constructor(public oxford: OxfordService, private route: ActivatedRoute, 
        private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(

          params => {
            //console.log(params);
            this.spinner.show();


            this.wordId = params.get('word_id');

            this.oxford.getDefinition(this.wordId).subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.o = data;
                this.title = this.o.word;
                this.definitions = this.getProperty(data, "definitions");
                this.examples = this.getProperty(data, "examples");
                this.lexicalCategories = this.getProperty(data, "lexicalCategory");

                this.pronunciations = this.getProperty(data, "pronunciations");
                this.origins = this.getProperty(data, "etymologies");


                this.lexicalCategories = this.removeDuplicateObjects(this.lexicalCategories);
                this.pronunciations = this.removeDuplicateObjects(this.pronunciations);
                this.origins = this.removeDuplicateObjects(this.origins);


                if (this.definitions.length > 0 || this.origins.length > 0 || this.examples.length > 0 || this.pronunciations.length > 0) {
                  this.displayInfo = true;
                }

                this.spinner.hide();

                console.log(this.lexicalCategories, this.pronunciations, this.origins);
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.spinner.hide();
                //const message = error.error.error;
                this.toastr.error(`${error.status},${error.error.error}`);
              }

            );

            this.oxford.getSynAndAnt(this.wordId).subscribe(
              data => {
                // console.log(data);
                this.synonyms = this.getProperty(data, "synonyms");
                this.antonyms = this.getProperty(data, "antonyms");

                this.spinner.hide();
                console.log(this.synonyms, this.antonyms);
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.spinner.hide();
                this.toastr.error(`${error.status},${error.error.error}`);
              }
            );

          }

        );

      }
```

Here is the html file

```
 <div class="card" *ngIf="definitions && definitions?.length>0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Definitions
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse thesaurus" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let def of definitions">
            {{def}}
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" *ngIf="examples && examples?.length>0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingEx">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEx"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseEx">
          Examples
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseEx" class="collapse thesaurus" aria-labelledby="headingEx" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ex of examples">
            {{ex.text}}
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" *ngIf="synonyms && synonyms?.length>0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Synonyms
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse container thesaurus" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body row ">

        <p class="col-6 col-md-4 border border-dark text-center" *ngFor="let syn of synonyms">{{syn.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" *ngIf="antonyms && antonyms?.length>0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
          Antonyms
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse container thesaurus" aria-labelledby="headingFour"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body row">

        <p class="col-6 col-md-4 border border-dark text-center" *ngFor="let ant of antonyms">{{ant.text}}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card" *ngIf="pronunciations && pronunciations?.length>0">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
          Pronunciations
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let pron of pronunciations">
            {{pron.phoneticSpelling}}
            <span *ngIf="pron.audioFile">
              <audio #audio [src]="pron.audioFile"></audio>
              <a (click)=play(audio)>
                <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here the screenshots :
[with synonyms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpFLW.png)

[error from thesaurus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V45KI.png)

[after page refresh or searching it before all other words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwAw3.png)

Comment: Because those object still hold the value? Don't see you setting the value to `null` whenever there's an error or not found.

Comment: You are not wiping out your prior values in your error logic. Have you tried to set the synonyms and antonyms to empty arrays in there?

Comment: I didn't do that .But I am not facing any issue with the data I get from entries endpoint which is the getDefinition() call like pronunciations,definitions,etc.

Comment: @AdityaReddy but think about what is going on. You are getting an error response and so your onError function is running and not your onNext function. Nowhere in that error function are you changing the state of your component (e.g. `this.synonyms` and `this.antonyms`), so we would expect no change in the UI. You will need to alter the state so that your template will not render those sections, which it looks like setting them to `null` or `[]` will do.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel  Setting those two to null in onError worked but I am not able to understand why  the data  from the getDefinition() didn't have any problem in updating the UI unlike  synonyms and antonyms.

Comment: @AdityaReddy it would be because the word existed and your service did not return an error for that. If that service ever returns an error, you would have a similar problem as this since you are not wiping out all of the state in the onError for that.

Answer (score 0):

you're not using ngOnInit in a way that I would use it. There are no Inputs so the lifecycle hook isn't really needed. Plus you're doing multiple subscribes inside another. I think your dependency here is the router param which kicks off the other two subscribes.

my advice is to assign the this.route.paramMap as a property (componentState$) in your TS and use the async pipe to subscribe to it within your template file via

```
<ng-container *ngIf="componentState$ | async as state"></ng-container>
```

in your ts, at the time just pipe off the params

```
 componentState$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => params.get('word_id')), 
      switchMap(wordId => combineLatest([
         this.oxford.getDefinition(wordId), 
         this.oxford.getSynAndAnt(wordId)
      ]).pipe(
            map(([def, synant]) => ({ def, synant }))
         )
      )
   );
```

your template will now have access to all your data in dot notation. Also, this means you only have one subscribe and you don't need to unsubscribe because your template async pipe will do both for you. No need to assign other props in your ts.